# how does pyspark broadcast variables work

Tags: python, apache-spark

I know it utilizes pickle and ship things across nodes and keep in memory and so on. what i'm confused is why the syntax on using it in pyspark work.

```
def main():
    sc = SparkContext()
    someValue = rand()
    V = sc.broadcast(someValue)
    A = sc.parallelize().map(worker)

def worker(element):
    element *= V.value
```

why the above code doesn't get a "V" not defined complaint? I searched the broadcast-related source code in pyspark but didn't get any clue.

Answer (score 4):

I believe your problem is simply a Python scope issue.  If you try the following non-Spark Python code, it'll similarly error with "'V' is not defined":

```
def runner(func):
    func()

def main():
    V = 22
    A = runner(worker)

def worker():
    print V

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

One fix is you can move `worker()` to be inside of `main()` (or alternatively, make `V` a global variable):

```
def main():
    sc = SparkContext()
    someValue = rand()
    V = sc.broadcast(someValue)
    def worker(element):
        element *= V.value
    A = sc.parallelize().map(worker)
```

Comment: Agreed on scoping. Here's an alternative answer for the worker function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26959221/pyspark-broadcast-variables-from-local-functions

Answer (score 2):

From Spark research papers
[Spark: Cluster Computing with Working Sets](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~matei/papers/2010/hotcloud_spark.pdf) 
Matei Zaharia, Mosharaf Chowdhury, Michael J. Franklin, Scott Shenker, Ion Stoica. HotCloud 2010. June 2010.

> Shared Variables: The two types of shared variables in
>   Spark, broadcast variables and accumulators, are implemented
>   using classes with custom serialization formats.
>   When one creates a broadcast variable b with a value v,
>   v is saved to a file in a shared file system. The serialized
>   form of b is a path to this file. When b’s value is queried
>   on a worker node, Spark first checks whether v is in a
>   local cache, and reads it from the file system if it isn’t.
>   We initially used HDFS to broadcast variables, but we are
>   developing a more efficient streaming broadcast system.

Comment: Thanks @Shawn, but this desn't answer my question on the "syntax".