# Spark RDD - Mapping with extra arguments

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

Is it possible to pass extra arguments to the mapping function in pySpark?
Specifically, I have the following code recipe:

```
raw_data_rdd = sc.textFile("data.json", use_unicode=True)
json_data_rdd = raw_data_rdd.map(lambda line: json.loads(line))
mapped_rdd = json_data_rdd.flatMap(processDataLine)
```

The function `processDataLine` takes extra arguments in addition to the JSON object, as:

```
def processDataLine(dataline, arg1, arg2)
```

How can I pass the extra arguments `arg1` and `arg2` to the `flaMap` function?

Comment: Consider reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26959221/pyspark-broadcast-variables-from-local-functions)

Comment: Thanks @AvihooMamka. As I understood I need to use partial function. But I've not got how to apply it to my case?

Comment: Why not send to the partial function the processDataLine function and the arguments you want after broadcasting it?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

1. You can use an anonymous function either directly in a `flatMap`

   ```
    json_data_rdd.flatMap(lambda j: processDataLine(j, arg1, arg2))
   ```

   or to curry `processDataLine`

   ```
    f = lambda j: processDataLine(j, arg1, arg2)
    json_data_rdd.flatMap(f)
   ```
2. You can generate `processDataLine` like this:

   ```
    def processDataLine(arg1, arg2):
        def _processDataLine(dataline):
            return ... # Do something with dataline, arg1, arg2
        return _processDataLine

    json_data_rdd.flatMap(processDataLine(arg1, arg2))
   ```
3. [`toolz`](https://github.com/pytoolz/toolz) library provides useful `curry` decorator:

   ```
    from toolz.functoolz import curry

    @curry
    def processDataLine(arg1, arg2, dataline): 
        return ... # Do something with dataline, arg1, arg2

    json_data_rdd.flatMap(processDataLine(arg1, arg2))
   ```

   Note that I've pushed `dataline` argument to the last position. It is not required but this way we don't have to use keyword args.
4. Finally there is [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) already mentioned by [Avihoo Mamka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2455626/avihoo-mamka) in the comments.

Comment: @guilhermecgs You can benchmark this on local collections but explicit nesting (2.) should be the most efficient followed by using anonymous function (1.) Currying / partials could be slightly slower because mechanism is much more sophisticated than the previous two. Not that I would really worry about it here.

Comment: I think there is a mistake in the first example, you mean:

f = lambda j: processDataLine( **j** , arg1, arg2)