# How to pass additional parameters to user-defined methods in pyspark for filter method?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using spark with python and I have a filter constraint as follows:

```
my_rdd.filter(my_func)
```

where my_func is a method I wrote to filter the rdd items based on my own logic. I have defined the my_func as follows:

```
def my_func(my_item):

{
...
}
```

Now, I want to pass another separate parameter to my_func, besides the item that goes into it. How can I do that? I know my_item will refer to one item that comes from my_rdd and how can I pass my own parameter (let's say my_param) as an additional parameter to my_func?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark RDD - Mapping with extra arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33019420/spark-rdd-mapping-with-extra-arguments)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using below lambda syntax and modify your my_func with extra parameters:

```
my_rdd.filter(lambda row: my_func(row,extra_parameter))
```